# Can I exchange data between child Rnw documents when using knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

The parent document is as follows:

```
<<child = "child1.Rnw">>=
@
<<child = "child2.Rnw">>=
@
```

Child 1:

```
<<>>=
set_parent("parent.Rnw")
x <- 1
@
```

Child 2:

```
<<>>=
set_parent("parent.Rnw")
x
@
```

I can run the parent document. However, I can not run the child 2 document alone. It seems that the child 2 document can not see variable `x` defined the in child 1 document. How can I run child 2 document alone?

Answer (score 4):

`set_parent` doesn't work the way you expect. From `?set_parent`:

> This function extracts the LaTeX preamble of the parent document to use for the child document, so that the child document can be compiled as an individual document.

`set_parent("parent.Rnw")` won't `knit` the whole parent document, it only extracts the preamble. Therefore, with this `parent.Rnw` file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<child = "child1.Rnw">>=
@

<<child = "child2.Rnw">>=
@

\end{document}
```

`child2.Rnw` cannot be compiled separately because `child1.Rnw` is not run in that case.

What works is the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
knit("parent.Rnw")
knit("child2.Rnw")
```

As both documents are evaluated in the same environment (see `knit`'s default `envir` value), objects from `parent.Rnw` (and it's child) can be used in the subsequent knitting of `child2.Rnw`.

Besides, `?set_parent` offers an alternative:

> When the preamble of the parent document also contains code chunks and inline R code, they will be evaluated as if they were in this child document.

If it is possible to rearrange `parent.Rnw` such that the chunk referencing `child1.Rnw` is in the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}

<<child = "child1.Rnw">>=
@

\begin{document}

<<child = "child2.Rnw">>=
@

\end{document}
```

then `child2.Rnw` can be knitted without prior knitting of `parent.Rnw`.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup><strike>For some reason, `knit2pdf("child2.Rnw")` crashes `pdflatex.exe` (called via `texify.exe`) on my system. However, the PDF file is correctly produced and running `pdflatex` directly on the TEX file causes no troubles.</strike> [Nevermind](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275125/37118).</sup>